# Concerns with using SSAS as an end user ad hoc reporting solution

Tags: reporting-services, ssas

I am currently evaluating reporting solutions for use within my organization and one of the requirements of the solution must be 'ad hoc reporting' and is defined as 'given an existing report the user will be permitted to modify the data points of the report and, additionally, save the report for later viewing'.

I worked through a basic report using SSAS and SSRS; this certainly worked but I found it to be a little bit to involved with needing to open report builder, specify the cube that should be used, and so on not to mention that the Report Builder (SSRS2K5) is pretty vanilla. The people that will be looking at these reports are certainly not technical people and my concern is that this process will be completely overwhelming. I did find [this component](http://www.datadynamics.com/products/ActiveAnalysis/Overview.aspx) and it is much more user friendly since the data source can be set dynamically at runtime and all the user has to focus on is what data they want to see.

Does SSAS/SSRS offer any other methods for ad hoc reporting other than using Report Builder to connect to cubes and going from there?  Does anyone know of, or used, any products similar to Active Analysis that they might recommend?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excel 2007 and 2010 actually has connection ability to adhoc query and analyze data from an SSAS cube. Excel have a host of features that allows interaction with the cube including using pivot tables and data mining plugins to analyze the data.

simple example here:
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/2016/using-excel-and-creating-a-pivot-table-report/

Answer (score 0):

SSRS2012 Power View in Sharepoint mode (soon in Excel) - overview is here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3726.power-view-overview-en-us.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what is meant by "user can modify the data points of the report" but with Excel 2007 / 2010 you can use the What If Analysis feature to modify the data in a pivot table. You can also combine that with Analysis Services writeback feature to enable some pretty cool data modelling functionality.

Comment: Assume you have a summary report that displays n fields but the user doesn't need fields x and y.  I need to have the ability for them to remove those from the report and also the ability to add fields a and b if necessary.

Comment: Excel (using pivot tables linked to a SSAS cube) would probably meet those "drag and drop column" requirements.  If your users have ever used standard pivot tables in Excel then they will already be familiar with the process.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for what I call "exploratory analysis" (i.e. you don't know what you're looking for in the analysis) then a product like our ActiveAnalysis component, PowerPivot, or Tableau are all good tools (note that a key difference being that our ActiveAnalysis is a developer component that you can cheaply embed into applications, and the other two are strictly end user tools).

However, if you have users who want to be able to create an "operational report" or they might want to customize existing reports those are probably not ideal tools. We actually created [ActiveReports Server](http://www.activereportsserver.com/) specifically for this type of scenario. It is a drag & drop business-user-friendly ad-hoc reporting tool that sounds like it might be more appropriate for the "not technical people" that it sounds like you're dealing with. It does not depend on SSAS and works all inside of a web browser, so nothing to deploy.

```
Scott Willeke
Product Manager | ActiveReports Server
GrapeCity
```

Comment: I demoed your products (AA, AR, and ARS) and while I loved AA I was put off by AR, specifically your help files.  I was doing a very basic POC (a summary report that contains a link to a details report (click through)) and followed along with the demo provided in the help files.  I had to go to the support website three times to either fill in the blanks missed by the help file or to correct errors that I found in the help files. That isn't to say I hold negative feelings towards your products, they are great, I was just a little put off by the lack of attention to detail in the help files.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Keeping help files full of information for every scenario that everyone encounters is a challenge to say the least. Ultimately the best way for us to improve help is to get feedback. So when you can't find someting you expect in the help, please drop us a quick note including which product (each of these products' help were handled by different teams altogether) and topics and or what you were looking for and unable to find.